# How to add google reCaptcha on the checkout page Magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, captcha

I want to add Google reCaptcha on the Checkout page.Is there any way to add google reCaptcha add on the checkout page?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/224290/magento-2-add-captcha-to-checkout-order-review-process

Comment: I see this extension but i want google reCaptcha,not native magento recaptcha.

Comment: you can try mageants [magento 2 google invisible recaptcha](https://www.mageants.com/google-invisible-recaptcha-for-magento-2.html) extension they providing captcha on checkout page

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the latest version Magento 2.4.5, then this is the default feature to enable the Recaptcha at the checkout process.

[image]

Please look into it to configure: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/security/google-recaptcha.html

Answer (score 0):

There are many extensions available online for Google Recaptcha. Checkout this extension - https://github.com/magespecialist/m2-MSP_ReCaptcha

You can take reference from this extension.

Answer (score 0):

Refer **[Amasty Google Invisible Recaptcha](https://amasty.com/google-invisible-recaptcha-for-magento-2.html)** You can add reCaptcha to your website/custom forms.

**Or**

You can refer **[Guide for Google Invisible reCaptcha](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/invisible)** for how to implement it in your site if you don't want to purchase any Extensions.

**Hope it Helps.**